Ethernet not working after updating OnePlus Nord (Android 12)
I have a OnePlus Nord running Android 12. Before the update, I connected the adapter RJ45 to USB-C and it worked fine. I don't remember switching on anything. Now it doesn't.
I have seen in the OnePlus community that they are removing the ethernet connectivity for some phones. But I asked the technical support and they said it was working.
